# Lodash remove duplicates from nested array

Tags: javascript, lodash

Just getting started looking over lodash and stuck trying to figure out how to remove duplicates from arrays within nested objects.

Working with loop:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let data = {
    "deviceA": {
        "serviceA": [
            "Foo",
            "Bar",
            "Foo Bar A",
            "Foo Bar A",
            "Foo Bar A"
        ],
        "serviceB": [
            "Foo",
            "Bar",
            "Foo Bar B",
            "Foo Bar B",
            "Foo Bar B"
        ]
    }
}


for (const key in data) {
    for (const key2 in data[key]) {
        data[key][key2] = _.uniqWith(data[key][key2], _.isEqual)
    }
}

console.log(data)
```

Is it possible using purely lodash to parse a nested object and update an array to remove duplicates without using a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine uniq and mapValues to achieve it.

```js
let data = {
    "deviceA": {
        "serviceA": [
            "Foo",
            "Bar",
            "Foo Bar A",
            "Foo Bar A",
            "Foo Bar A"
        ],
        "serviceB": [
            "Foo",
            "Bar",
            "Foo Bar B",
            "Foo Bar B",
            "Foo Bar B"
        ]
    },
    "deviceB": {
        "serviceA": [
            "A",
            "A",
            "Foo Bar A",
        ],
        "serviceB": [
            "B",
            "B",
            "Foo Bar B",
        ]
    }
}

const items = _.mapValues(data, (device) => _.mapValues(device, (service) =>_.uniq(service)))
console.log(items)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can consider a solution without lodash, below is an example of how this can be implemented natively using pure js.

```js
let data = {
    "deviceA": {
        "serviceA": [
            "Foo",
            "Bar",
            "Foo Bar A",
            "Foo Bar A",
            "Foo Bar A"
        ],
        "serviceB": [
            "Foo",
            "Bar",
            "Foo Bar B",
            "Foo Bar B",
            "Foo Bar B"
        ]
    }
}

const noDup = Object.entries(data).reduce((p, n) => {
  const a = Object.entries(n[1]).reduce((p1, n1) => 
    ({...p1, [n1[0]]: [...new Set(n1[1])]})
  , {})
  return {...p, [n[0]]: a}
}, {})

console.log(noDup)
```

Comment: Accepted the lodash specific one for the use case, but like this pure implementation as well.

Comment: Thats okay, Though consider avoiding lodash, You should aim at making your project as small as possible and if a library can be avoided then avoid it

Comment: Yes I saw a lot of question that solve by native javascript. That's is really awesome. But I think that is a trade off between the stable of the code, readable, support functions of lodash with source code size.